# Unknown sensor chevy spark 800cc

Tags: chevrolet, part-identification, sensor

[image]

I just got my wife's car back from the mechanic who fixed it. He told me that there is a sensor which has no piping connected to it, and he have no idea where it should be connected.

The issue is, I do not know what the sensor is called, so I cannot use a simple google search to try and find out how it should be connected and what its actual function is. It would be great if someone can identify the sensor for me and probably also tell me what it does, and where it should be connected. Just a note, it is electrically connected to the car, it is just the mechanical connections I'm after.

### EDIT

Additional info as requested

1. It is 2005 model Chevy Spark 800cc
2. The only numbers and words on the sensor are *5F24* and *KONG HWA*
3. The two wires connected to the sensor are red and grey respectively

Comment: Three questions: 1) What year is your Spark? 2) Are there *any* numbers on it, stamped, imprinted, otherwise, on it? 3) What are the wire colors on the connector going to this and can you provide a picture of the connector?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 thanks for the feedback, have added extra info via an edit

Comment: Besides the connector picture, could you see about a picture of where this part is located at in the engine bay? This would be a "guilt by association" type thing. Hopefully knowing what it is near and where it is located may help in the identification.

Comment: judging from the two separate nozzles , my guess would be that  it's a pressure differential sensor. It could also be a secondary air pump or someting, but it doesn't look like one. are those two lumps at the back electrical connectors?

Comment: It looks like either a vacuum switch or a washer pump to me. What work was done to the car that he found this part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Vacuum Valve Solenoid (vacuum regulator), [Part #96333470](http://www.gmpartsdirect.com/oe-gm/96333470)

(from [Ali Express](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/New-OE-Quality-25183354-Vacuum-Valve-Solenoid-for-Chevrolet-Aveo-Epica-Daewoo-Lanos-Matiz-Lacetti-96333470/32669847920.html?spm=2114.40010708.4.38.3Lxllo))

[image: https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1Xdi1JVXXXXXlaXXXq6xXFXXXv/New-OE-Quality-25183354-Vacuum-Valve-Solenoid-for-Chevrolet-Aveo-Epica-Daewoo-Lanos-Matiz-Lacetti-96333470.jpg_640x640.jpg]

I can't find any references that this was used in the Spark, only the Aveo and Epica.

Still looking...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I took your info and did my own research aswell. It does seem that the part is not used on the chevy spark or daewoo matiz (engines are the same) as I also cannot find any info on it. What I'll do is, when I come across the same car, I will ask the owner to take a peek. If I have additional info, I will post that info. Anyways, your answer was the first one, so I'm happy to accept it

Answer (score 1):

It's not a sensor, it is an solenoid/actuator.

The part is a Vacuum Solenoid used to direct vacuum pressure to certain vacuum operated parts or actuators.

It could connect to a number of things such as:

- Turbo Vane/Wastegate actuator
- Intake Manifold Flaps
- EGR valve

and many other things.

The best way to find out what it does is to hook the car up to a diagnostics machine with 'Actuators' function. Hook up a multimeter to the solenoid, you could then operate each actuator through the diagnostics one by one until the voltage changes on the meter.

Comment: Thank you for the addional info. It does seem that the part is not used on  chevy spark. I wil however keep looking, will try to find a similar car and peek under the hood to confirm whether or not the part is actually used or not. If I find additional info, I will post it as well